# One of my three Google Fonts isn't loading, and I don't know why

Tags: fonts, google-webfonts

I'm having a curious problem with Google Fonts. I'm using three fonts: Lora for the body; Ubuntu for all titles, nav links, widget titles, etc.; and a third one for the website title in the header.

Lora and the website title font always load without any problems. But Ubuntu doesn't always load, and I don't know why. Since my website uses fonts as the primary design element, it really breaks my design.

I'm rural and do have internet problems, but like I said, this only happens to Ubuntu. Just a few minutes ago, I refreshed a page on my website and the fallback serif font loaded instead of Ubuntu. Can you please help figure out why this is happening?

Here's what I'm noticing, and I don't know if this is part of the problem:

1. In the Safari developer tool, I can see two error messages. One says this:

"Did not parse stylesheet at 'http://moosenotes.com/wp-content/themes/moose?ver=cd9b96051512f036e7eb10bffa428d46' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode."

The other error message is this:

"Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost." On the far right of this text is this link: http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ubuntu/v8/sVvvcJDRTINJla2R4XwPVevvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.ttf

I'm not sure what any of this means.

2. I load Google Fonts via my stylesheet. I've read it's best to put them in functions.php, but I'm not sure how best to do this. It seems some people aren't doing this correctly, from what I've seen in different blog posts.
3. I know when Google Fonts is loading, it may display the fallback font, which I've set to 'serif,' and that's the font I'm seeing. But probably half of the time, Ubuntu is not loading at all.

Do you have any idea why this keeps happening? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The one culprit I have seen in the past is plugins slightly modifying the URL of the web fonts. Do you have a URL I can take a look at to try figure out what’s going on?

You can also try following this guide to see if you can fix it.

https://siteorigin.com/troubleshooting/identifying-plugin-conflicts/

Comment: Thanks, Josh. The website is MooseNotes.com. Someone on Twitter gave me a link to read, and based on that I headed over to my hosting company to see if it could be a server problem. This is the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files . I'm in a chat session with them right now, waiting for their response. This really has me stumped, but I do agree that I should also consider plugins as the problem. I have so few, but I could try testing them and see if the error message in the developer tool goes away.